# Benefit of importing specific parts of a Haskell module

Tags: haskell, module

Except from potential name clashes -- which can be got around by other means -- is there any benefit to importing only the parts from a module that you need:

```
import SomeModule (x, y, z)
```

...verses just importing all of it, which is terser and easier to maintain:

```
import SomeModule
```

Would it make the binary smaller, for instance?

Comment: idk if it would make a binary smaller but it can be nice if there are function collisions for functions you don't need.  Instead of importing a qualified module and then typing what you imported it as over and over again.  You can just import the parts you need and not have to import qualified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's only for the purpose of preventing name clashes. The other mechanism for preventing name clashes - namely `import qualified` - results in more verbose (less readable) code.

It wouldn't make the binary smaller - consider that functions in a given module all reference each other, usually, so they need to be compiled together.

Answer (score 11):

Name clashes and binary size optimization are just two of the benefits you can get. Indeed, it is a good practice to always identify what you want to get from the outside world of your code. So, whenever people look at your code they will know what exactly your code requesting.

This also gives you a very good chance to creat mocking solutions for test, since you can work through the list of imports and write mockings for them.

Unfortunately, in Haskell the type class instances are not that easy. They are imported implicitly and so can creates conflicts, also they may makes mocking harder, since there is no way to specify specific class instances only. Hopefully this can be fixed in future versions of Haskell.

**UPDATE**

The benifits I listed above (code maintenance and test mocking) are not limited to Haskell. Actually, it is also common practice in Java, as I know. In Java you can just import a single class, or even a single static variable/method. Unfortunately again, you still cannot selectively import member functions.

Comment: I second this answer. Think of people who come later and try to read your code; if your module uses a function called `frobnicate`, how do they know which of the imported modules it came from? They can grep or Hoogle it, but maybe there are multiple modules that define functions of that name, which then they need to cross-reference with the imports, etc. It's nicer to just be more specific in your imports—though it's not a hard and fast rule either.

Comment: If they can open that module in GHCi then `:i frobnicate` will usually tell you the file it was found in. It may be possible to get this through ghc-mod as well.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson What if you *can't* open the module in GHCi because compilation fails with a message about `frobnicate` not being defined? The explicit import tells you where it was *supposed* to come from, which can be vitally important when you're picking up old code that once worked but needs to be forward-ported.

Comment: Oh, I agree that the explicit import is useful. I'm building a style guide now and definitely including it. I'd really enjoy an automatically generated one as well. `:i` doesn't solve all problems, but it's useful to know about.